# Why does this C program print 3 2 15 instead of 2 3 20?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
   int i, j, m;
   i = ++a[1];
   j = a[1]++;
   m = a[i++];
   printf("%d, %d, %d", i, j, m);
}
```

Can you please explain the logic behind this program?

Comment: Because the value of `i` is changed twice, and the last change to `a[1]` is not relevant.

Comment: Write a little chart on paper showing the value of every variable (including the array elements) after each line is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this (or use your debugger, or just think it through maybe with the help of a piece of paper)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
    int i, j, m;
    i = ++a[1]; fprintf(stderr, "i is %d; a[1] is %d\n", i, a[1]);
    j = a[1]++; fprintf(stderr, "j is %d; a[1] is %d\n", j, a[1]);
    m = a[i++]; fprintf(stderr, "m is %d, i is %d; a[i] is %d\n", m, i, a[i]);
    printf("%d, %d, %d", i, j, m);
}
```

See [code running on ideone](https://ideone.com/AoFzaC).

Answer (score 3):

The increment operator (`++`) behaves different depending on the location with respect to the expression. i.e `++foo` first increments the variable `foo`, then yields the incremented value for the expression. However, `foo++` gives you the value of `foo`, but `foo` is incremented if you'd like to further use it.

So the line-by-line analysis would look like this:

`i = ++a[1]`:  `a[1]` is `1`, its incremented value is `2`. Hence, the variable `i` gets the value `2`.

`j = a[1]++`: Remember that `a[1]` is `2` now. So the value of expression is `2`. Hence `j` gets the value `2`. But `a[1]` is incremented, getting the value `3`.

`m = a[i++]`: The value of `i` is 2. It's incremented, but that value is not being used here, the old value is used. So, `a[2]` is being accessed here. Thus, `m` becomes `15`.

In the end, `i` is `3`, `j` is `2` and `m` is `15`.

Edit: The discussion of `++` operator is not totally technical, as pointed out in the comments. I just adopted an educational way to explain things. @pmg describes what is actually happening in the comments section.

Comment: Nitpick: "*`++foo` first increments the variable `foo`, then yields the incremented value for the expression*" is not technically accurate. The value of `++foo` is foo+1. The expression has the side effect of incrementing `foo`. When the increment to `foo` happens is not necessarily before or after `foo+1` is used in the "main" expression.

Answer (score 0):

For two reasons.

Number one, `i++` modifies `i`, making it equal to `3`.

Number two, the post-increment operator increments the value by `1` but returns the original value. So not only you're modifying `i`, you're also getting the wrong value out of it. Same for `j`, once again you're incrementing `a[1]`, making it `2+1=3`, but the operator returns the original value which is `2`. To return the new value, use the pre-increment operator.

This is the fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
   int i, j, m;
   i = ++a[1];
   j = ++a[1];
   m = a[i+1];
   printf("%d, %d, %d", i, j, m);
}
```

This gives you `2, 3, 20`.

Comment: Fixed code? OP was not looking for a code fix, but for an explanation of the behavior of the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze it line by line:

```
i = ++a[1];
```

Here we first increase the value of `a[1]` by 1 and then assign it to `i`.

Result: `a[1] == 2`, `i == 2`

```
j = a[1]++;
```

Here we first assign the value of `a[1]` to `j`, and then increase the value of `a[1]` by 1.

Result: `a[1] == 3`, `i == 2`, `j == 2`

```
m = a[i++];
```

Here we first assign `a[i]` to `m` and then increase `i` by 1.

Result: `a[1] == 3`, `i == 3`, `j == 2`, `m = 15`

This will be an useful reference to understand it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence